How can I filter the prime ng table and export only filtered data to excel
I have a primeng table where I am trying to export the filtered data to excel, I have create a table as component and using it where ever required. Here is the stackblitz code I am working on. I am using exceljs and file-saver npm packages to export the data. The only issue I had is to download only filtered data instead of all.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-card-demo-azewpe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts
I have gone through this link but no luck https://medium.com/@sankarums/angular-primeng-table-export-only-filtered-data-to-excel-7fc97878099c
this.table.filteredValue this always gives me null
In the given example let us say I select client1 and click on export to excel it should download only the rows that belongs to client1

I am able to figure it out I added one more property in my component
 @Input()
 filteredvalues: any[] = [];

Added onfilter method (onFilter)="onFilter($event)"
onFilter(event: any) {
    this.filteredvalues = event.filteredValue;
}

Imported the component as viewchild @ViewChild('dt1') table!:PrimeTableComponent;
and on export I did this
exportToExcel() {
   if (this.table.filteredvalues && Array.isArray(this.table.filteredvalues)) {
   let data: any[] = [];
   this.table.filteredvalues.forEach((employee: any) => {
   const rowData: any = {
   'Employee ID': employee.employeeId,
   'Full Name': employee.employeeName,
   'Email': employee.emailId,
   'Billing Status': employee.billingStatus,
   'Designation': employee.designation,
   'Client': employee.client,
   'Billing Start Date': employee.billingStartDate
  };
 });

  if (data.length > 0) {
    saveAsExcelFile(data, "EmployeeData");
  }
  }
}

